# The limit set by CnosDB "ALTER TENANT tenant_name _limiter=......" is inaccurate

Tags: cnosdb

I set a limit for a tenant during my local testing. The SQL restriction is as follows:

```
ALTER TENANT tenant_name _limiter='{
    "comment": "",
    "limiter_config": {
    "object_config": {
    "max_users_number": 1,
    "max_databases": 1,
    "max_shard_number": 1,
    "max_replicate_number": 1,
    "max_retention_time": 1
},
"request_config": {
    "data_in": {
        "remote_bucket": {
        "max": 100,
        "initial": 0,
        "refill": 100,
        "interval": 100
    },
        "local_bucket": {
            "max": 100,
            "initial": 0
        }
    },
    "data_out": {
        "remote_bucket": {
            "max": 100,
            "initial": 0,
            "refill": 100,
            "interval": 100
        },
        "local_bucket": {
        "max": 100,
        "initial": 0
        }
    },
    "queries": {
        "remote_bucket": {
            "max": 100,
            "initial": 0,
            "refill": 100,
            "interval": 100
        },
        "local_bucket": {
            "max": 100,
            "initial": 0
        }
    },
    "writes": {
        "remote_bucket": {
            "max": 100,
            "initial": 0,
            "refill": 100,
            "interval": 100
        },
        "local_bucket": {
            "max": 100,
            "initial": 0
        }
    }
}
}
}';
```

After successful setup, my 'data_in' is being restricted by the limiter even before reaching 50, preventing further write access. May I know what could be the reason behind this situation?